# CSS canvas width and height setting

Tags: javascript, css

I am creating canvas element with javascript like

```
Can=document.createElement("canvas");
```

Then I want to set the width of this element in centimeters. I am doing

```
Can.style.width="8cm";
Can.style.height="5cm";
```

I am setting other css properties like,

```
Can.style.cssText = 'position:relative; top:24px; left:28px; border-radius:30px; float:left; cursor:pointer; box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px black; background-color:#cdcdcd';
```

But it is not being set. What's is the problem? How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the canvas size in pixels. You can then scale the canvas using `cm` as units.

```
canvas.width = 500; // px
canvas.height = 300; // px

canvas.style.width = '5cm';
canvas.style.height = '3cm';
```

The number of pixels in a canvas has to be explicitly/absolutely defined. Centimeters are a relative value.

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
Can.width = "5px";
Can.height = "5px";
```

cm are not recomendeed

Comment: Well you are wrong. I want to use cm. And i got the issue and resolve it.

Comment: My question was not that!!! So that's why you are wrong. But thanks for giving link of recommendations :)

Comment: never use cm on the web, nothing here is cm based.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's recommended or not the answer had absolutely nothing to do with the actual question itself. At best it should have been a comment and not an answer.