# setting width and height of canvas with css scales the whole thing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I have a canvas that I would like to be able to customize the size of. However, when I set the `width` and `height` properties in CSS, the entire canvas is scaled. Additionally, I cannot set it back with `ctx.scale(1,1)` in JS.

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048948/css-canvas-width-and-height-setting) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227038/setting-the-canvas-width-and-height-with-css-shifts-the-pen) question which have no acceptable solution.

Here is my relevant code:

**HTML:**

```
<img id="sprites-img" src="roguelikeSheet_transparent.png">
<canvas id="user-map"></canvas>
```

**CSS:**

```
#user-map {
    transform: scale(1,1);
    width: 512px;
    height: 256px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$( ()=> {
    $('#user-map').click( (evt)=> {
        let clickX = evt.offsetX;
        let clickY = evt.offsetY;

        console.log(clickX, clickY);

        let mapX = Math.floor(clickX/16)*16 ; // not working, scaled incorrectly
        let mapY = Math.floor(clickY/16)*16  ;

        console.log(mapX, mapY);

        placeSprite(mapX, mapY);
    });
});

function placeSprite(mapX, mapY) {
    let startX = selectedSprite[X]*17 - 1;
    let startY = selectedSprite[Y]*17 - 1;

    let ctx = document.getElementById('user-map').getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(mapX, mapY, 16, 16);
    ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('sprites-img'), startX, startY, 16, 16,
        mapX, mapY, 16, 16);
}
```

I am aware of the specs of `ctx.drawImage()`, as described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).

Comment: What is **selectedSprite** here?

Comment: both question you link have the needed solution which is using attribute instead of CSS. This is how canvas works

Comment: The solution was to do this:

 canvas.setAttribute('width', window.innerWidth);
 canvas.setAttribute('height', window.innerHeight);

Answer (score 0):

That's by design. Scaling the canvas will scale everything inside of it by default. Just put the canvas inside a div container with 
`display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;`
and scale that.

I'm not 100% clear what you're hoping to accomplish if that doesn't work please give a little more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried adding:
#canvas-container {
 width: 512px;
 height: 256px;

 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
and 
<div id="canvas-container">
  <canvas id="user-map"></canvas>
 </div>
and it still does not work.

It just doesn't scale the canvas at all.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is make the canvas larger (width and height) without it automatically scaling and distorting images drawn on it.